# How to implement adaptive payment in 'in-app-purchase' api in IOS applications

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to ios application development. I want to use 'in-app-purchase' api. Does it facilitate developers to split payment b/w application owner and vendors, like paypal's adaptive payment.

Comment: No, you'll need to manage any payment routing on your own.